# Finding constant in electrostatic equation given only charge

Tags: electromagnetism, em

So in a region of free space with zero charge, all I'm given is that the electrostatic potential V is given by:

$$V(x,y,z) = kz(x^2) y + 2y - 6y(z^3)$$ [Volts]

To find the constant *k*, would I have to use the assumption that there is zero electric field and that the corresponding partial derivatives dV/dx, dV/dy, and dV/dz also equal to zero?

Comment: Between the plates of a charged capacitor in a vacuum there is no charge. And yet the field is not zero. You should try to catch another fish, mon ami.

Answer (score 0):

Why electric field is zero? It is a gradient of potential

$$
E=-grad(V)
$$

Now use Maxwell's equation for electric field taking into account that there is now electric charge in your space

$$
\mathrm{div}\,E = 0
$$

Then combine the two equations

$$
\mathrm{div}\,\mathrm{grad}\, V=\Delta V=0
$$

Where \$\Delta\$ is a [Laplace operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator).

Apply the operator to your equation for V and you should be able to solve it for k.